# CSS properties to both the "html" and "body"

Tags: css

I've seen this quite a few times now. When people want to assign a CSS property to the whole window/document, they sometimes do

```
html, body {
   myCSSProperty: someValue;
}
```

For example, see the answer I accepted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809351/height-100-doesnt-seem-to-work-for-table), or see [this article](http://www.phpbb.com/kb/article/css3-rounded-corners-for-prosilver/).

I am wondering if assigning CSS properties to both `html` and `body` is to overcome browser bugs, required for all browsers, a purely psychological thing, a common misconception or misunderstanding of the tags `html` and `body`, or something else.

I would be glad if someone could demystify the situation for me, separating the cases where CSS properties need to be assigned to `html` or `body`, or both, with specific examples and explanations.

Comment: `height` for example needs to be assigned to both, because it's relative to its parent element. That way you can ensure it extends to the whole viewport

Comment: Lots and lots of good info is retrievable using this obvious query: http://www.google.com/search?q=html+vs+body+css

Comment: @Iwburk: Interestingly, not that many relevant results from the last year: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=HTML+vs+BODY&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a#q=HTML+vs+BODY&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=U2b&tbo=1&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&output=search&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:y&sa=X&ei=suKdTrKTG82aOo3uwfgI&ved=0CAsQpwUoBQ&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=6266eee4fc2b1327&biw=1271&bih=652 The articles in your search are pretty damn old, talking about stuff like scrollbar color properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://phrogz.net/css/htmlvsbody.html) has great information about the `<html>` and `<body>` tags in terms of CSS. The short of it is this (taken from the top of the article):

- The `html` and `body` elements are distinct block-level entities, in a parent/child relationship.
- The `html` element's height and width are controlled by the browser window.
- It is the `html` element which has (by default) `overflow:auto`, causing scrollbars to appear when needed.
- The `body` element is (by default) `position:static`, which means that positioned children of it are positioned relative to the `html` element's coordinate system.
- In almost all modern browsers, the built-in offset from the edge of the page is applied through a `margin` on the `body` element, **not** `padding` on the `html` element.

Comment: Excellent article reference.  I commented above on why, since body is `position:static` does it make a difference.  I think the best nugget from the article is this: [Because body isn't positioned (or more accurately, it's `position:static` by default), setting a child element to `height:100%` causes it to be 100% of the height of the html element, not the body element. Thus, if you want something to be as tall as the body is (going down past the bottom of the page) use
body { position:relative }.]  I haven't tested this but assume it's correct.